Верно ли, что все неизменяемые объекты в Python представлены в виде единых экземпляров?
В Python есть два вида проверок: равенство (==) и идентичность (is).
Рассмотрим код ниже:
a = 10
b = 10
print(a == b)  # True, потому что обе переменные ссылаются на объекты с одинаковым значением
print(a is b) # True ???

В части print(a is b) происходит сравнение ссылок a и b. Поскольку результат оператора идентичности равен True, получается, что обе переменные имеют одинаковые ссылки.
Поскольку любые переменные, которым мы присвоим какой-то неизменяемый объект, имеют одинаковую ссылку на этот объект, значит ли это, что все неизменяемые объекты представлены в виде единых экземпляров в памяти?

У вас is равно потому что а) в питоне числа вроде до 255 представлены единственным экземпляром для оптимизации б) компилятор может вычислить всё и не создавать лишних переменных. Возьмите рэндом (значение которого доступно только в рантайме) и число побольше и будем вам False

Обсуждался вопрос этот много раз. Надо бы найти чему он дубликат.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1592984/562052

Спасибо, первый ответ в вопросе ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1592984/562052 полностью закрыл все имеющиеся у меня вопросы)
